# Progressbar in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-progressbar

I am working on a android project in which there will be a Recyclerview consisting of items(rows). At run time whenever item(row) is added to the Recyclerview, it starts uploading to server and updates the progressbar in that item(row). Each Item here is a file. Everything goes fine as long as the items are added till the size of the screen. Whenever items cross the screen limit, I would need to scroll. While scrolling, progressbar updating on different item. sometimes on two or more items. After googling a lot, I understood that it is because of the Recyclerview reusing already created viewholders.

here is my Adapter Code of recyclerview:

```
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView filename;

    private ProgressBar file_progressbar;

    public MyViewHolder(View v) {

        super(v);

        filename = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.filename);

        file_progressbar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.file_progressbar);

    }

}


    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    final String fname = fDataset.get((fDataset.size() - 1) - position);

    File f = new File(fname);

    holder.filename.setText(f.getName());
             if(internetchek.isNetworkAvailable(this.ctx))
             {

                 holder.file_progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                 upload up = new upload(this.ctx,fname,holder.file_progressbar,"uploadstart");

                 up.execute();
             }
            else {

                 Toast.makeText(this.ctx, "Offline", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             }


        }
```

I have passed holder.file_progressbar into upload class. So that the progressbar gets updated in Upload class. I am not getting any idea how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try to add separate flags for your data like this

```
private boolean isItemUpdating(int position) {
     return mDataUpdatingFlags[position];
}

private void setItemUpdating(int position, boolean isUpdating) {
     mDataUpdatingFlags[position] = isUpdating;
}
```

Then in your `onBindViewHolder` call these method to setup your progress correctly:

```
if (isItemUpdating(position) {
    holder.showProgressBar();
} else {
    holder.hideProgressBar();
}
```

Comment: It is solving only a part of the problem. Whenever more than screan size rows are uploading at a time. Progress bar of one row is showing for another row update vice versa.

Comment: @sandesh, it actually addresses this problem. Whenever the number of the recycler rows is big enough to cover a screen height, the recycler will call `onBindViewHolder` to recycle existing views to new items at the specified position. Could you post the code you've tried?